# How to install maven2 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, maven-2

I'm trying to install maven2 on Ubuntu using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

But it install maven3 instead of maven2. I want a project from maven and the projects are managed by Maven2 build system. How to install from command line?

Comment: I try this But i didn't work .It shows an error Package 'maven2' has no installation candidate

Comment: Why would you like to install Maven 2? ([Maven 2 is End Of Life](https://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html))...

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

This command install latest version of maven.

```
sudo apt-get purge maven maven2 maven3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andrei-pozolotin/maven2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maven2
```

Try This command, you can get maven2 version.

OR

You can download it from official site:

```
https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
```

Answer (score 2):

Download it from the official site:

```
$ wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-2/2.2.1/binaries/apache-maven-2.2.1-bin.zip
$ unzip apache-maven-2.2.1-bin.zip
```